# Query Oracle SqlDeveloper

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, rdbms

I want to write a SELECT statement to create a list of jobs containing the job_title and the mean value of the two fields  MIN_SALARY and MAX_SALARY sorted from the highest mean value to the lowest.

I wrote this:

```
select job_title, MAX_SALARY, MIN_SALARY, count(*)
from HR.EMPLOYEES, HR.JOBS
order by count(*) desc
group by j.job_title;
```

but it gives error:

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended 00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
```

[image]

[image: Here you are. You see at #4 and at left the tables]

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should have this query

```
select job_title, MAX_SALARY, MIN_SALARY, count(*)
from HR.EMPLOYEES, HR.JOBS
group by job_title
order by count(*) desc
```

I have reordered the clauses and removed the spurious `j`

See - [select](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm)

Comment: Yes I agree that is better, but now it gives me ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: Would help to have the tables